# How to remove line breaks using shell

Tags: xml, linux, shell, unix

Please help with your expertise. Having a xml file as below with hidden line break in age.

```
<name>david</name>
<age>27</age>
<gender>male</gender>
```

When I execute cat -e filename it shows as below

```
<name>david</name>$
<$
age>27</age>$
<gender>male</gender>$
```

How to remove this hidden line break on age so that it will look as below

```
<name>david</name>
<age>27</age>
<gender>male</gender>
```

Comment: What is the character?

Comment: @Shawn  When I open the xml file in notepad++ and apply show all characters. It does not show any character on age. But shows line split on cat -e command. 
Actuallly I'm trying to parse the xml file and this line break causing issue.

Comment: have you considered using `xmllint`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try sed or tr

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' file.txt or sed -i "s/\n/ /g" file.txt
```

to replace the newline with space or

```
tr -d '\n' < input.txt > output.txt
```

or `tr --delete '\n' < input.txt > output.txt` to remove.

You may need to do some hit and trial to achieve this, I have tried in txt file, for xml, I am not sure how it will behave.

but the easiest way will be paste in some IDE and format the file, that will get your job done I guess.

Comment: sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' file.txt  
This one helped to fix the issue.

Comment: Yes. That worked. Thanks much for your timely help.

Comment: @Sen I am glad I could help you :)